# Does AWS S3 copy to same bucket preserves TTL (Expiration date - Lifecycle Policy)?

Tags: amazon-s3

When copying data from `s3://bukcet1/aaa to s3://bucket1/bbb` - does the ttl (Lifecycle Policy) of the objects preserves?

That is - if the bucket ttl is 10 days and I copy an object that is 9 days old, would the ttl be reseted to 10 days, or will be object be removed in a day?

Comment: What do you mean by a "bucket TTL"?

Comment: By TTL I mean - time to live.
That is - what is the retention policy of the files in the bucket. 
Is there a better terminology?

Comment: Are you referring to an Amazon S3 Lifecycle Policy? If so, please add that to your question.

Comment: Please let me know if this is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked this manually and I found that the copied files (objects) are set to a current "Last modified" data and their TTL (Expiration date) is set to according to the bucket policy from the "Last modified" time